# Perl, modifiers /m /s/ /ms

Tags: regex, perl, reference-book

I have seen in Larry's Wall book `programming Perl 3rd edition` what do the modifiers
/s
/m
/ms

in some **example** with `\n` . Now I cannot find the exact page.

Specifically the example showed that only the last modifier /ms work.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Finding the page number in 3rd edition in the book.

Comment: I don't think that finding a book's particular page numbers is a scope of this site. The mods might close this question.

Comment: `/s` changes the behaviour of `.`, `/m` changes the behaviour of `^` and `$`.